# jquery tooltib plugin / so confused for choosing / sorry for duplicate

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, mouse, tooltip

i am really really confused for choosing a good plugin for tooltipls of images inside a listview (repeater) - tooltip content comes from database...

i worked some days on this without any good result...

for this purpose i can not use the below nice plugins , because they don't support html (mean div or span under trigger) and we should set title attribute for getting tooltip:

mean [bassistance](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) or [qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/)

besides i want a tooltip that support mouse tracker like upper tooltips...

but those plugins only support title for getting tooltip.

so sorry for duplicate , i really would be appreciate for helping me about this...

Comment: qtip2 allows you to specify the tooltip content

Comment: thanks for answer / but how it works for listview (div as tooltip inside itemTemplate with fields from db after an image as trigger) - mean which selector should i use (id or class)?

Comment: we can not use id as selector in jquery content / besides if we use class so how it works ? (which class appears for an item in list view?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that works nicely:

basically what it does is  on the mouseover of the thing you want to have the tooltip, it checks if it's got one yet,  and if it doesn't it finds the div you want to be the content and makes that it's tooltip.  after it's attached it,  it triggers the mouseover so that it shows.

```
$(".TipMe").live("mouseover", function (event) {

        var $this = $(this);
        var tipContent= $(this).parents('td').find('.classOfToolTIpContent').html();
        if (!$this.data("toolTipAttached")) {
            $this.data("toolTipAttached", true)

            $this.qtip({
                overwrite: true,
                content: tipContent,
                show: {
                    delay: 65,
                    ready: true,
                    solo: true
                },
                hide: {
                    fixed: true,
                    delay: 300
                },
                style: {
                   widget: false,
                    tip: {
                        corner: true,
                        border:1,
                        height:15,
                        width:15


                    }
                },
                position: {
                    target: 'mouse',
                    adjust: {
                        mouse: false,
                        screen: true
                    }
                }
            },
           event);
            $this.trigger("mouseover");
        }

    });
```

Comment: REALLY THANKS AND GOD BLESS U / LET ME TEST IT AND TELL U THE RESULT!